# Why is this "obviously" false condition returning true?

Tags: c#, wpf, boolean

In my test scenario, all of the combo boxes have the same value displayed ("<--Select-->").

```
private bool AtLeastOnePlatypusSelected()
{
    string DefaultPlatypusValue = "<--Select-->";
    return (cmbxWeek1.SelectedValue != DefaultPlatypusValue) ||
           (cmbxWeek2.SelectedValue != DefaultPlatypusValue) ||
           (cmbxWeek3.SelectedValue != DefaultPlatypusValue) ||
           (cmbxWeek4.SelectedValue != DefaultPlatypusValue) ||
           (cmbxWeek5.SelectedValue != DefaultPlatypusValue) ||
           (cmbxWeek6.SelectedValue != DefaultPlatypusValue) ||
           (cmbxWeek7.SelectedValue != DefaultPlatypusValue) ||
           (cmbxWeek8.SelectedValue != DefaultPlatypusValue) ||
           (cmbxWeek9.SelectedValue != DefaultPlatypusValue);
}
```

...yet this function is returning true.

Here's the other combobox code:

```
public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> cbItems { get; set; }
public ComboBoxItem SelectedcbItem { get; set; }
private Dictionary<int, int> PointNumToWeekNumPairings = new Dictionary<int, int>();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;

    cbItems = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>();
    var cbItem = new ComboBoxItem { Content = "<--Select-->" };
    SelectedcbItem = cbItem;
    cbItems.Add(cbItem);
    cbItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Tony Iommi" });
    cbItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Mike McCarthy" });
    cbItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Micah Profit" });
    cbItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Allan Poe" });
    cbItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Bill Bailey" });
    cbItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Duane Eddy" });
    cbItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "John Kennedy" });
    cbItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Bert Erneson" });
    cbItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Clyde Valouch" });
    cbItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Micky Thompson" });
}
```

What the Pork Link Wray Charles Dickens is going on here?!?

Comment: Can you share the code for the combo boxes ?

Comment: Step through in the debugger and check if the `SelectedValues` are all the same and not `null`.

Comment: Did you consider the possibility of case sensitivity?

Comment: @Tim, et al: Sorry, this is WPF; I tagged it as such now.

Comment: @cyclotrojan: xaml is <ComboBox x:Name="cmbxWeek1" Width="160" ItemsSource="{Binding cbItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedcbItem}" SelectionChanged="cmbxWeek1_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>

Comment: Check out the answer of @Mark Hall. Is your `SelectedValuePath` correct? Ehm, sorry. He removed his answer. Use `SelectedItem` if you do not have a `SelectedValuePath`.

Comment: i love it when you said "obviously" in the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your example is a Winforms example, [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.LISTCONTROL.SELECTEDVALUE%29;k%28SELECTEDVALUE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) is an object containing the value of the member of the data source specified by the ValueMember property. If you do not have a ValueMember Assigned use the `SelectedItem` Property instead.

---

Be aware that the SelectedValue property and SelectedItem property in WPF return ComboBoxItem objects so you are comparing a `ComboBoxItem` to a String. Try changing your comparison to something like this:

```
private bool AtLeastOnePlatypusSelected()
{

    string DefaultPlatypusValue = "<--Select-->";
    return (string)((ComboBoxItem)cmbxWeek1.SelectedValue).Content != DefaultPlatypusValue ||
           (string)((ComboBoxItem)cmbxWeek2.SelectedValue).Content != DefaultPlatypusValue ||
           (string)((ComboBoxItem)cmbxWeek3.SelectedValue).Content != DefaultPlatypusValue ||
           (string)((ComboBoxItem)cmbxWeek4.SelectedValue).Content != DefaultPlatypusValue ||
           (string)((ComboBoxItem)cmbxWeek5.SelectedValue).Content != DefaultPlatypusValue ||
           (string)((ComboBoxItem)cmbxWeek6.SelectedValue).Content != DefaultPlatypusValue ||
           (string)((ComboBoxItem)cmbxWeek7.SelectedValue).Content != DefaultPlatypusValue ||
           (string)((ComboBoxItem)cmbxWeek8.SelectedValue).Content != DefaultPlatypusValue ||
           (string)((ComboBoxItem)cmbxWeek9.SelectedValue).Content != DefaultPlatypusValue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue.aspx) returns an `object`. It is very likely that at least one of the involved strings is not interned, causing the `object` comparison (which is always a reference comparison) to return false.

Comment: How is that likely? Also all the strings are supposedly the same so it should use the one and only interned instance.

Comment: @H.B.: Only constant strings are interned. There are a lot of ways to get a non-interned string, heck `"a" + "b" != (object) "ab"` if you have optimizations turned off. In either case, he needs to actually check the values rather than assume they are all the same, but 3 others had said that, so figured I would throw a random potential in there.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** As i thought, you manually create `ListBoxItems`...

The selected value is a `ListBoxItem`, of course it's not equal to a `string`, set the `SelectedValuePath` to `"Content"` or just drop the `ListBoxItems` and add the strings directly, the control will create the containers for you (this is usually to be preferred, one should not have UI elements in the data collections, it also allows for virtualization)

---

> all of the combo boxes have the same value displayed ("<--Select-->").

Display != value, there are some properties that define what is shown and what is selected.
e.g. if you have database entries you may want the [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue.aspx) to be the primary key (which is some integer), so you set the [`SelectedValuePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath.aspx) accordingly, but to the user the numbers mean nothing so you set the [`DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) to some property containing a meaningful name or description.

Check what those properties are set to (if you have no `SelectedValuePath` it will be the complete item, i.e. `SelectedValue == SelectedItem`). Also, if all your entries are wrapped in manually created `ListBoxItems` you of course get `ListBoxItem != string`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
private bool AtLeastOnePlatypusSelected()
{
    string DefaultPlatypusValue = "<--Select-->";
    return (!cmbxWeek1.SelectedValue.Equals(DefaultPlatypusValue) ||
       (cmbxWeek2.SelectedValue.Equals(DefaultPlatypusValue) ||
       (cmbxWeek3.SelectedValue.Equals(DefaultPlatypusValue) ||
       (cmbxWeek4.SelectedValue.Equals(DefaultPlatypusValue) ||
       (cmbxWeek5.SelectedValue.Equals(DefaultPlatypusValue) ||
       (cmbxWeek6.SelectedValue.Equals(DefaultPlatypusValue) ||
       (cmbxWeek7.SelectedValue.Equals(DefaultPlatypusValue) ||
       (cmbxWeek8.SelectedValue.Equals(DefaultPlatypusValue) ||
       (cmbxWeek9.SelectedValue.Equals(DefaultPlatypusValue));
}
```

In general, you want to test for "equalness" of two objects by using the "Equals" method.

In C#, a "==" comparison is more akin to testing whether or not the two objects are the same instance which is something you'll rarely be doing (and clearly not what you want, in your example).

Edit:  So it turns out, this is NOT the case for strings in C#.

Comment: "Something you'll rarely be doing"? Really? You must have different experiences than I do.

Comment: Er, that's Java. In C#, `==` for many/most types works almost exactly like `.Equals` (main difference is that `Equals` will throw an exception if called on a `null` instance)

Comment: @jalf: `==` by default is reference equality. It is overloaded for strings to mean value equality.

Comment: @KendallFrey: It is overloaded for a lot of types to mean value equality. But since we're dealing with strings in *this* case, I think the behavior for strings is very relevant. ;)

Comment: Ah, learned something new.  Didn't realize it was overrloaded (to a sensible) behavior  for strings.

Comment: @Kendall: YMMV, but I'm pretty sure that value equality is vastly more common than instance equality. That C# deviated from Java seems like a case-and-point.

Comment: @jalf: We aren't dealing with strings.  We're dealing with `object` property return value, pointing to objects whose dynamic type is `System.String`.  But operators are chosen based on the static type.  -1 to your comment and +1 to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array` or `List` of ComboBoxes:

```
var cmbxWeeks = new List<ComboBox>();
cmbxWeeks.Add(cmbxWeek1 ...
```

and

```
private bool AtLeastOnePlatypusSelected()
{
    string DefaultPlatypusValue = "<--Select-->";

    bool result = true;
    foreach (var cmbxWeek in cmbxWeeks)
        result = result  || (cmbxWeek.SelectedValue != DefaultPlatypusValue);

    return result;
}
```

or in LINQ way

```
return cmbxWeeks.Aggregate(true, (current, cmbxWeek) => current || ((string) cmbxWeek.SelectedValue != DefaultPlatypusValue));
```

Comment: This question was not asking for refactoring.

Comment: Would be better if this explained the what cmbxWeeks is, why using an array of controls is a lot better.. Also would be nice to use LINQ

Comment: @KendallFrey Its our duty to give people the right answer, even if they are asking the wrong question (fix this terrible code vs whats the right way to do this)

Comment: @MichaelBaldry: It is not our duty to give equivalent but prettier code, when an error is the problem. It is our duty to answer questions.

Comment: @KendallFrey There is a difference between pretty and doing things correctly. Checking 9 Combos separately for the same value is NOT correct.

Comment: @MichaelBaldry And why not? As I said before, this 'solution' does not change the behaviour, so how could it *possibly* be considered an answer? It is at best a poorly presented comment.

Answer (score 1):

> What the Pork Link Wray Charles Dickens is going on here?!?

Obviously, one or more of the comboboxes have a different `SelectedValue` than you expect.

Step through the code in a debugger, or print out the values.

Answer (score 1):

Try SelectedItem rather than SelectedValue

I wrote a quick little test program and found SelectedValue of my comboboxes equal to null, but SelectedItem had the text I expected and return false.

(My apologies, my test was in WinForms...)

OK, my *new* test shows that SelectionBoxItem will return the string and should give you the results you want.

Answer (score -1):

I had to change the code to this for it to work:

```
return ((!(cmbxWeek1.SelectedValue.ToString().Contains(DefaultPlatypusValue))) ||
        (!(cmbxWeek2.SelectedValue.ToString().Contains(DefaultPlatypusValue))) ||
        (!(cmbxWeek3.SelectedValue.ToString().Contains(DefaultPlatypusValue))) ||
        (!(cmbxWeek4.SelectedValue.ToString().Contains(DefaultPlatypusValue))) ||
        (!(cmbxWeek5.SelectedValue.ToString().Contains(DefaultPlatypusValue))) ||
        (!(cmbxWeek6.SelectedValue.ToString().Contains(DefaultPlatypusValue))) ||
        (!(cmbxWeek7.SelectedValue.ToString().Contains(DefaultPlatypusValue))) ||
        (!(cmbxWeek8.SelectedValue.ToString().Contains(DefaultPlatypusValue))) ||
        (!(cmbxWeek9.SelectedValue.ToString().Contains(DefaultPlatypusValue))));
```

Comment: You really ought to refactor that using some kind of collection object to make it more readable. Also, did you ever use a debugger to determine what value was in `SelectedValue`?

Comment: That is a *horrible* way to do this, please read my answer. You rely on the string representation of `ListBoxItems` to conain the content, which is completely arbitrary and may even change in future releases if you are unlucky.